# Converging extracted sentences and counting predicted label for each paragraph

Tags: java, knime

I'm having a problem with knime. I have some paragraphs in an excel file and I want to find out how many sentences are assertive, declarative in each paragraph. So, I have a dataset with labeled sentences. I have built a model on that dataset. Now, I used that dataset to predict the sentences of the paragraphs by using SentenceExtractor node and applied the model and model gives the prediction. Now, the problem is the prediction is on sentences and I need to know how many sentences are assertive, etc in each paragraph. How should I join the extracted paragraph sentences and count each paragraphs sentence's predict and record them into an excel file?

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried rowID and groupBy nodes. But I couldn't make it

Answer (score 0):

You should use Pivoting node. Group column should be label (column) which sentence belongs to which paragraph, pivot column is your prediction column and aggregation method is count on any other column.

Comment: Thanks. I really understand you now but one last query. How can I know which sentence belongs to which paragraph? Is it something we do before splitting into sentences?

Comment: Try joining your prediction with output from Sentence Extractor node for example cause there you have same amount of rows. Then from there you should define your paragraph by extracting one (maybe better more to be sure to be unique) first words from documents. Then the use of Pivoting node will give you number of sentences per paragraph.